# Finding similar image from a database based on a picture

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-recognition

I have the following problem. I am working for a company that orders a lot of trading cards from different shops.
We order a trading card after a customer ask us to find a particular one based on a picture. The following process is happening :

- Customer send us a request for a trading card he wants: usually, he sends us a picture
- We find and order the trading card
- When the trading car is received a staff has to manually find the corresponding trading card from a list of pictures of all pending orders. I spare you the details but the picture of the image is the only relevant info that allows us to find the order.

What I wish to build is a setup where the admin will pass the trading card under a camera. The camera will take a picture, hash the image, and compare it to a hash of the product image we already have on the database from the user order request.

Our web app is running with Laravel. I found this package that could do the work :
https://github.com/jenssegers/imagehash

So I would hash the picture of the item received and compare it to the image hash already store in the DB from customer request. And retrieve similar results.

I am blocked with the hardware part. Not sure what kind of camera I should use.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: any camera and lighting will do if it can produce a decent picture. why do you think you are blocked on that? perhaps p-hashes are too simple? the problem is called "content based image retrieval".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Il will start to look on this direction